# Pagination: Server Side or Client Side?

Tags: javascript, pagination, client-side, server-side

What is it best to handle pagination? Server side or doing it dynamically using javascript?

I'm working on a project which is heavy on the ajax and pulling in data dynamically, so I've been working on a javascript pagination system that uses the dom - but I'm starting to think it would be better to handle it all server side.

What are everyone's thoughts?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The right answer depends on your priorities and the size of the data set to be paginated.

**Server side pagination is best for:**

- Large data set
- Faster initial page load
- Accessibility for those not running javascript

**Client side pagination is best for:**

- Small data set
- Faster subsequent page loads

So if you're paginating for primarily cosmetic reasons, it makes more sense to handle it client side. And if you're paginating to reduce initial load time, server side is the obvious choice.

Of course, client side's advantage on subsequent page load times diminishes if you utilize Ajax to load subsequent pages.

Comment: What is small size data is question now

Comment: @Pushpendra Small enough that you can practically send it all to the user and expect their browser to be able to filter and sort the data as needed. So testing your targeted platforms is important.

Comment: I would add that if the expectation is the user will look at the first page and then move on (like in use case of a search result) then server side paging will be less resource intensive.

Answer (score 10):

Doing it on client side will make your user download all the data at first which might not be needed, and will remove the primary benefit of pagination.

The best way to do so for such kind of AJAX apps is to make AJAX call the server for next page and add update the current page using client side script.

Comment: If load times matter, it might be a good idea to pre-load the next page whenever a page is loaded. That would result in zero load times unless someone forwards by two pages very quickly.

Answer (score 7):

If you have large pages and a large number of pages you are better of requesting pages in chunks from the server via AJAX. So let the server do the pagination, based of your request URL.

You can also pre-fetch the next few pages the user will likely view to make the interface seem more responsive.

If there are only few pages, grabbing it all up-front and paginating on the client may be a better choice.

Answer (score 6):

Even with small data sizes the best choice would be server side pagination. You will not have to worry later if your web application scales further.

And for larger data sizes the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 5):

Server side - send to the client just enough content for the current view.

Answer (score 4):

In a practical world of limits, I would page on the server side to conserve all the resources associated with sending the data. Also, the server needs to protect itself from a malicious/malfunctioning client asking for a HUGE page.

Once that code is happily chugging along, I would add "smarts" to the client to get the "next" and "previous" page and hold that in memory. When the user pages to the next page, update your cache.

If the client software does this sort of page caching, do consider how fast your data ages (is likely to change) and if you should check that your cached page of data is still valid. Maybe re-request it if it ages more than 2 minutes. Maybe have a "dirty" flag in it. Something like that. Hope you find this helpful. :)

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean that your JavaScript has all the data in memory, and shows one page a time? Or that it downloads each page from the server as it's needed, using AJAX?

If it's the latter, you also may need to think about sorting. If you sort using JavaScript, you'll only be able to sort one page at a time, which doesn't make much sense. So your sorting should be done on the server.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer server side pagination.  However, when implementing it, you need to make sure that you're optimizing your SQL properly.  For instance, I believe in MySQL, if you use the LIMIT option it doesn't use the index so you need to rewrite your sql to use the index properly.

G-Man

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to point out here is that very rarely will you be limited to simply paging through a raw dataset.

You might have to search for certain terms in one or more columns you are displaying, and then say sort on a few columns and then give the users the ability to page through this filtered dataset.

In a situation like this you might have to see whether it would be better to have this logic search and/or sort client side or server side.

Another thing to consider is that Amazon's cloud search api gives you some very powerful searching abilities and obviously you'll want to allow cloud search to handle searching and sorting for you if you happen to have your data hosted there.