# JQGrid page Navigation with JSON data inside GSP(groovy server pages)?

Tags: jquery, json, grails, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

First thing I want to know that which type of pagination is more preferable (Client side or Server side) in "jqGrid" structure for gsp page.

> My issue is that when I set "loadonce:true" then automatically sorting
>   is work and navigation icons(arrows) are getting disabled. When I comment
>   out "loadonce:true" then sorting stop working and navigation arrows are
>   enabled but not working at all.

I'm using following things in my project and my page navigation is not working.

**Cotroller**

```
class TestDBController {

    def dataSource


    def index = {

    }

    def jq_customer_list = {

        try {
            def sql = new Sql(dataSource)

            String query = "select * from employee"
            List customers = sql.rows(query)
            def count1 = sql.rows(query).size()
            def jsonCells = customers.collect {
            [cell: [it.fname,
                    it.lname,
                    it.age,
                    it.id ] 
            ]           
            }                   
            def jsonData= [ rows: jsonCells]
            render jsonData as JSON     
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Generated exception is "+e)
        }
      } 
}
```

**GSP** with jqgrid code -

**css and javascript** files -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'timeTable.css')}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css',file:'ui.jqgrid.css')}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css/ui-lightness',file:'jquery-ui-     1.9.2.custom.css')}"type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'ttajqgridtable.css')} "type="text/css">

<g:javascript src="jquery-1.8.3.js" />
<g:javascript src="grid.locale-en.js" />
<g:javascript src="jquery.jqGrid.min.js" /> 
<g:javascript src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" />
```

**JQuery** code

```
<body>
        <table id="list" class="scroll jqTable"></table>
        <div id="pager" class="scroll"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
             jQuery("#list").jqGrid({

                  url:'${g.createLink( controller:'TestDB', action:'jq_customer_list' )}',
                  datatype: "json",               
                  colNames:['first Name','Last Name','Age','id'],
                  colModel:[
                    {name:'fName'},
                    {name:'lName'},
                    {name:'age'},
                    {name:'id'}   
                  ],
                  rowNum: 5,
                  width : 1000,
                  height: 500,
                  shrinkToFit: true,
                  pager: "#pager",
                  paging: true,
                 viewrecords: true,
                 gridview: true,
                 loadonce:true,              
                  rowList : [ 5,10, 25],                 
                  sortname : 'fname',
                  viewrecords : true,
                  sortorder : "desc",                
                  rownumbers: true,                  
                  altRows:true,                 
                  caption: "Division Data"                
                });
             jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'});
             jQuery("#tabs").tabs();             
            });           
            </script>

    </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a small resultset to work with, and you are certain it will never grow, then client side pagination is probably fine. If you're working with larger sets of data, then you will want to implement server side pagination.

There is a more thorough discussion about the differences between client and server side pagination [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407878/pagination-server-side-or-client-side).

In order to implement server side pagination with jqgrid, you will need to do something with the `max` and `offset` parameters that jqgrid submits to your controller's `jq_customer_list` action. It's actually pretty straightforward, take a look at the [Groovy `Sql` docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#asList%28java.lang.String,%20java.sql.ResultSet,%20int,%20int,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) for an example.

Comment: In controller I'm getting 2000 records on an average, so which type of pagination is fine for me.

Comment: You'll need to make a judgement call - if the time taken to pull those 2000 records onto the client and sort/search through them etc while they're all there is acceptable then you're probably better off going with client side pagination as it's less work to implement...

Answer (score 0):

loadonce is implemented with JQGrid 3.7. If want to implement proper Pagination, Sorting and Searching just use never versions(latest one) of jqGrid.

Here is my **working example** -

**CSS and JS** file with proper order -

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="${resource(dir:'css/ui-lightness',file:'jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css')}"type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet"href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'ttajqgridtable.css')}" type="text/css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css',file:'ui.jqgrid.css')}" type="text/css">

<g:javascript src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" />
<g:javascript src="grid.locale-en.js" />
<g:javascript src="jquery.jqGrid.min.js" /> 
<g:javascript src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" />
```

**Jquery and JQGrid** code -

```
    <script type="text/javascript">           
        $(document).ready(function () {
         jQuery("#clist").jqGrid({

              url:'${g.createLink( controller:'TableDataJQgrid', action:'jq_customer_list' )}',
              datatype: "json",
              mtype:"post",
              colNames:['first Name','Last Name','Age','id'],
              colModel:[
                        {name:'fName', width:120, sortable: true, editable: true, align: 'center' },
                        {name:'lName',  width:120, sortable: true, editable: true, align: 'center'},
                        {name:'age',   width:80, sorttype:"int", sortable: true, editable: false, align: 'center'},
                        {name:'id' ,  width:80, sorttype:"int", sortable: true, editable: false , align: 'center'}

              ],
              rowNum: 5,
              width : 1000,
              height: 500,
              shrinkToFit: true,
              pager: "#list_pager",
              paging: true,
              viewrecords: true,
              gridview: true,
              loadonce:true,                
              rowList : [ 5,10, 25],  
              rowTotal: 21,               
              sortname : 'fname',
              viewrecords : true,
              sortorder : "desc",                
              rownumbers: true,                  
              altRows:true,                 
              caption: "Division Data"
          });
       jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#list_pager'{edit:false,add:false,del:false});         
        });           
        </script>
```