# How to make next page link when document size reaches to specific length?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have built an Admin section where i can see all the contents from database in a table. everything is fine but if the database table has thousands of rows I have to scroll down very deep. is there any way I can make links like `1,2,3.Next   the way google search results do? or is there any even better way?

```
    Isn't is going to be something like:

             if($(document).height>2000){
        //what should i do?
}
```

Comment: Sure, it's called pagination just google you way around including specific server side language you might be using.There are two types 1.Non-ajax (page gets reloaded like google) 2.Ajax ( content added by ajax like instagram).Former is simpler you don't need javascript for that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using jquery. If you are going to implement everything on your own it may be time consuming - although it would be fun!
To save some time, there are quite a few plugins available to achieve this. Refer:

- https://datatables.net/
- http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Client-side-HTML-Table-Pagination-Plugin-with-jQuery-Paging.html

Since you may have huge data you should be using server side pagination instead of client side. Here is another SO link which explains the difference between them : [Pagination: Server Side or Client Side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407878/pagination-server-side-or-client-side)